# How to use two internet connections independently

Tags: network, wifi, internet, torrent

I have two internet connections, the one is high speed and I connect to through WiFi and the other is a slow PPPoE connection. I have a 5 gig cap for the WiFi connection and a 20 gig cap for the PPPoE connection so the idea is that I use WiFi for general internet browsing, emails etc and the PPPoE connection for torrents.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to use both at the same time. Is there any way that I can setup my torrent client to only use the PPPoE connection, and not the WiFi?

Comment: Which torrent client are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is an admittedly convoluted method, but you could run the torrent app in a vm. Vbox, Parallels, Fusion, whichever. Then you can bind the vm's networking to a specific network interface. The default for the vm networking is usually "Auto" which means it uses what the Mac uses and that's dictated by the service order in the Networking System Prefs. But you can also bind to a specific interface and that will keep the vm's traffic on that connection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Bind your torrent client to the desired interface.  Azureus (vuze) for example has this functionality in advanced settings mode.  The client will show your available interfaces and associated [local] ip addresses to help you choose.  If your client does not perhaps you could switch.  You'll additionally gain the ability to

1. block connections from horrible/poor clients (useragent filtering via plug-in) -- preventing wasting your resources on non-sharing peers
2. limit transfer speed by time of day (plug-in)
3. block connections from horrible/poor clients (useragent filtering via plug-in)